# Fluent NHibernate: Custom condition (WHERE clause) on get, update and delete

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table that contains information from many customers

```
ID | employeename | customerId
------------------------------
 1 | employee1    |  188
 2 | employee2    |  188
 3 | employee3    |  177
```

Now I would like to get only those employees, whose customerId is 188. How do I map this with Fluent NHibernate so, that on update and delete there would also be `WHERE customerId = 188` ?

Current Mapping is something like:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Name).Column("employeename");
Map(x => x.CustomerId).Column("customerId");
```

Adding `Where("customerId = 188")` only results custom where clause in SELECT. I would need following UPDATE-clause to happen on saveorupdate.

```
UPDATE employees SET employeename="employ" WHERE ID = 2 AND customerId = 188;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking wrong with this SQL mind in your head.

1) Add HasMany( x => x.Employees ).Inverse().AsSet(); in your Customer class.
2) Add References( x=> x.Customer ); in your Employee class.

This is called bidirectional mapping.

Look here: http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/NHibernate-inverse3dtrue-and-cascade3dsave-update-demo.aspx

The idea is that you create your objects and you assign values to them. After that NHibernate executes SQL statements if you have proper mapping files. Dont write your sql queries and then forcing NHibernate to generate exactly the same ones. Instead write your mappings and see what SQL NHibernate generates and try to optimize it.

PS: Dont forget to add the cascade...

Comment: Actually the customerId is more like access control. I didn't plan to have Customer-class at all (it is not really a domain model in my case). On the other hand if I make the Customer class I don't want it to have Employees-property at all.

Comment: Then drop the (2) in your Employee class. HasMany should do the rest.